# java.sql: Validate ResultSet format

Tags: java, validation, jdbc

I want to parse a `java.sql.ResultSet` into a `Map<String, String>`, and I want to validate three things:

- The first column should be named `key` and should be of type `String`
- The second column should be named `value` and should be of type `String`
- There is no third column

Here is what I have so far in my class `HiveStatementOutputContent`:

```
protected Map<String, String> keyValueOutput;

public HiveStatementOutputContent(ResultSet s) throws Exception {

    if(s.findColumn("key") != 0 )
        throw new Exception("Error in SQL result: First column has to be 'key'.");
    if(s.findColumn("value") != 1)
        throw new Exception("Error in SQL result: Second column has to be 'value'.");

    //TODO: Validate type

    //TODO: Validate number of columns

    while ( s.next() )
    {
        keyValueOutput.put(s.getString(0),s.getString(1));
    }
}
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I hope you are aware that `ResultSet` columns are 1-based, not 0-based. So `s.findColumn("key")` will **never** return `0` (and if it does, that would be a serious bug in your driver).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I found that out the hard way, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about which item gets inserted as the key and which gets inserted as the value, I think it is much simpler to just use column aliases when iterating over the `ResultSet` and getting the Strings.

```
while ( s.next() )
{
    keyValueOutput.put(s.getString("key"),s.getString("value"));
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(java.lang.String)

You don't get the validation of the `key` being before the `value` in the SQL result, but you decouple your code bit from the SQL, since all the code above cares about is that there are a `key` and a `value` column (either by exact column name in SQL, or by an `AS` alias in the SQL query).

If you want to verify the order of the columns, their names, and datatypes, you can use the `ResultSetMetaData` object by calling `s.getMetaData()`.  You can then call `metadata.getColumnName(int)` and `metadata.getColumnType(int)` to verify the column's name and datatype.  You can also leverage `getColumnCount` to verify you are not pulling any extra columns.
See:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnName(int)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnType(int)

Comment: I *want* to validate. That's the point! Please do not assume what I am trying to achieve. I want to show an Error when the `ResultDataset` doesn't look right, even if it would maybe work.

Comment: Ah, I interpreted that you wanted to just get the data by name when using hard-coded index values.  I have edited my answer to add how to do validation.